# Why does my Automapper config not work, even though AssertConfigurationValid passes?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following entities:

```
public class ContactDetailsJson
{
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string SeoContactUrl { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactUrl { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public bool Owned { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string ContactId { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalContactSearchResultsViewModel
{
    public int DisplayedPageNumber { get; set; }
    public int TotalResultsCount { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public IList<ContactResultViewModel> Results { get; set; }

    public class ContactResultViewModel
    {
        public string ContactId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Headline { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string PublicUrl { get; set; }
        public bool HasAccess { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

To support the conversion, I have the following mappings created, which I have verified are being run:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<ContactDetailsJson, ExternalContactSearchResultsViewModel.ContactResultViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Company, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CompanyName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ContactId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ContactId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.HasAccess, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Owned))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Headline, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Title))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastUpdatedDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UpdatedDate))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PublicUrl, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Unfortunately, this mapping results in all properties being null (or default values), as can be seen from the following unit test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Automapper_Contact_Details_Json_Can_Be_Mapped()
    {
        // Setup
        EntityMapLoader.LoadEntityMappings();
        DateTime testDate = DateTime.Now;

        var json = new ContactDetailsJson
        {
            CompanyName = "company",
            ContactId = "12345",
            FirstName = "first",
            LastName = "last",
            Owned = true,
            Title = "title",
            UpdatedDate = testDate
        };

        // Act
        var result = Mapper.Map<ContactDetailsJson, ExternalContactSearchResultsViewModel.ContactResultViewModel>(json);

        // Verify
        Assert.IsNotNull(result, "result was null");
        Assert.AreEqual("company", result.Company);
        Assert.AreEqual("12345", result.ContactId);
        Assert.AreEqual("first", result.FirstName);
        Assert.AreEqual("last", result.LastName);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, result.HasAccess);
        Assert.AreEqual("title", result.Headline);
        Assert.AreEqual(testDate, result.LastUpdatedDate);
    }
```

I can't figure out what is wrong.  Does anyone else see anything?

Comment: tried Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()?

Comment: Yes, no exceptions are thrown

Comment: Is the createmap in the test setup?

Comment: Yeah the createMaps are loaded via the `LoadEntityMap` call.  I have double checked that with breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it works for me, I think its something wrong in way you are loading mapping or check if you are using latest version of automapper

```
 [TestFixture]
public class UnitTest
{

    [Test]
    public void Automapper_Contact_Details_Json_Can_Be_Mapped()
    {
        // Setup 

        DateTime testDate = DateTime.Now;

        var json = new ContactDetailsJson
        {
            CompanyName = "company",
            ContactId = "12345",
            FirstName = "first",
            LastName = "last",
            Owned = true,
            Title = "title",
            UpdatedDate = testDate
        };
        Mapper.CreateMap<ContactDetailsJson, ExternalContactSearchResultsViewModel.ContactResultViewModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Company, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CompanyName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ContactId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ContactId))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.HasAccess, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Owned))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Headline, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Title))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.LastUpdatedDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UpdatedDate))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.PublicUrl, opt => opt.Ignore()); 

        // Act 
        var result = Mapper.Map<ContactDetailsJson, ExternalContactSearchResultsViewModel.ContactResultViewModel>(json);

        // Verify 
        Assert.IsNotNull(result, "result was null");
        Assert.AreEqual("company", result.Company);
        Assert.AreEqual("12345", result.ContactId);
        Assert.AreEqual("first", result.FirstName);
        Assert.AreEqual("last", result.LastName);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, result.HasAccess);
        Assert.AreEqual("title", result.Headline);
        Assert.AreEqual(testDate, result.LastUpdatedDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm probably not using the latest automapper, I'll check when I get home.  My loading strategy has had zero issues so far for other mappings, even mappings that are defined in the same method as these mappings so I don't know why this would be different

Comment: Updating to the latest Automapper on Nuget seems to have fixed it.  Guess I should have thought of that before :)